# Trying to copy folder to folder on linux (raspberry pi)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Hi I am new to Python and having some issues as follows

I have got a python script with a little gui and I can get it to run fine on my windows box but cannot get it to do the same on my Raspberian OS, it will not find / copy the folder I am pointing it to

here is the code

```
# Copy App
# Copies files from a predetermined source to path

import os
import shutil
from tkinter import *

cfsourcePath = r'/dev/sdb1' # Source path of data normally a USB card reader
cfdestPath = r'/dev/sda1' # Dest path of folder normally a USB hdd direct to root

ctsourcePath = r'/dev/sda1' # Source path of data normally a USB HDD
ctdestPath = r'//192.168.1.100/datadump' # Dest path of folder normally a NAS/server

class Application(Frame):
""" GUI application which copies files. """ 
def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialize the frame. """
    super(Application, self).__init__(master)
    self.grid(padx=10,pady=10)
    self.create_widget()

def create_widget(self):
    """ Create button for copying from source. """
    self.bttn1 = Button(self, width=18, height=7)
    self.bttn1["text"]= "Copy from Source"
    self.bttn1["command"] = self.copysource
    self.bttn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    """ Create button for copying to destination. """
    self.bttn2 = Button(self)
    self.bttn2["text"]= "Copy from Dest"
    self.bttn2["command"] = self.copydest
    self.bttn2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

def copysource(self):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cfsourcePath):

        #figure out where we're going
        dest = cfdestPath + root.replace(cfsourcePath, '')

        #if we're in a directory that doesn't exist in the destination folder
        #then create a new folder
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.mkdir(dest)
            print('Directory created at: ' + dest)

        #loop through all files in the directory
        for f in files:

            #compute current (old) & new file locations
            oldLoc = root + '\\' + f
            newLoc = dest + '\\' + f

            if not os.path.isfile(newLoc):
                try:
                    shutil.copy2(oldLoc, newLoc)
                    print('File ' + f + ' copied.')
                except IOError:
                    print('file "' + f + '" already exists')

def copydest(self):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ctsourcePath):

        #figure out where we're going
        dest = ctdestPath + root.replace(ctsourcePath, '')

        #if we're in a directory that doesn't exist in the destination folder
        #then create a new folder
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.mkdir(dest)
            print('Directory created at: ' + dest)

        #loop through all files in the directory
        for f in files:

            #compute current (old) & new file locations
            oldLoc = root + '\\' + f
            newLoc = dest + '\\' + f

            if not os.path.isfile(newLoc):
                try:
                    shutil.copy2(oldLoc, newLoc)
                    print('File ' + f + ' copied.')
                except IOError:
                    print('file "' + f + '" already exists')


# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Card Copy App")
root.geometry("320x240")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the bit this is working on windows but not on linux
WINDOWS

```
cfsourcePath = r'E:/DCIM' # Source path of data normally a USB card reader
cfdestPath = r'C:/Datadump' # Dest path of folder normally a USB hdd direct to root
```

Linux (Raspberian OS)

```
cfsourcePath = r'/dev/sdb1' # Source path of data normally a USB card reader
cfdestPath = r'/dev/sda1' # Dest path of folder normally a USB hdd direct to root
```

I can see both the USB devices on linux but when I press the button to copy it does nothing but doing the same on windows it works each time.

Can anyone help me out to see where I have gone wrong

EDIT - ADDED INFO

so after a bit more playing and re-imaging the RPi, I managed to get both USB card reader and USB HDD to different mount points but when running the script it seems to look at the empty destination directory as being the source folder and it just says the files already exsist, but again doing this on a windows pc it works fine........... anyone have any ideas

Comment: Linux has directories, not folders.

Comment: Hi, so looking at the issue can you see the problem as I am just trying to copy directly from the root directory of the USB card reader to the root of the USB hdd

Comment: You want to copy from the mount point of one to the mount point of the other. Make sure that both are mounted. You don't want to copy directly from the devices .

Comment: Hi, Ok cool, I shall try that so it should look something like this ?
cfsourcePath = r'/CFUSBMNT' # Source path of data normally a USB card reader
cfdestPath = r'/HDDUSBMNT' # Dest path of folder normally a USB hdd direct to root